# Web development with Clojure book: Swagger-ui not recognizing edn

Tags: clojure, luminus, edn

I am working through Web Development with Clojure, Third edition, by Dmitri Sotnikov and Scott Brown.

In Chapter 5, "Setting up for success" we add support for swagger-ui.

On page 117, we are told that we should downgrade Swagger UI to get support for EDN by adding

```
[metosin/ring-swagger-ui "2.2.10"]
```

to the project dependencies.

However, even after doing this, EDN still does not work.

When I try to get all messages, I get `Unrecognized response type`

When I try to post a message, nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This was occurring only because of browser caching.

Once I used the browser's developer tools and disabled caching (in Chrome, under View->Developer->Developer Tools, Network tab), everything worked as expected.